# MySQL Partitioning, Delete old data from multiple related tables

Tags: mysql, myisam

I am new to MySQL partitioning, therefore any example will be appreciated.

I am trying to create a sort of an ageing mechanism for a data that is distributed between several MyISAM tables.

My question will actually include several sub-questions.

The relevant tables are:

1. First table contains raw data with high input frequency (next to each record there is an auto incremented id).
2. Second table contains processed results, there is a result record per every raw data record (result record contains the source id record of the auto incremented field of raw data record)

Questions:

1. I need to be able to partition the raw data table and result data table similarly so that both of them will include only 10 weeks of data in single partition (each raw data record contains unixtimestamp field), how do i do it , can someone write small example case for two such tables?.
2. I want to be able to change the 10 weeks constraint on the fly.
3. I want that when ever the current partition will be filled or a new partition is created , the previous (10 weeks before) partition will be deleted automatically.
4. I don't want the auto increment id integer to be overflown, as much as i understand the ids are unique for the partition only, so if i am not wrong the auto increment id will start from zero for the next partition? but what if the previous partition still exist, will i have 2 duplicated ids , how i know to reference only for the last id when i present a result record?
5. I want to load raw data using LOAD DATA INTO... instead of multiple inserts , is MySQL partitioning functionality affected?

And the last question, would you suggest some other approach to implement aging mechanism (i am writing Java implementation product that processes around 1 GB or raw data per day and stores the results in MySQL)

Comment: Why are you partitioning this if you are deleting the last block of data every time you create a new partition? Why not just have a pair of tables (raw data and processed data) that you truncate whenever they are 'full'?

Comment: @ethrbunny: i want the previous (10 weeks before) partition to be dropped- this mean that i have in memory at least 2 partitions all the time. Ideally i would like to keep at least 10 weeks of data (configurable) in DB all the time, and after several batch inserts i will start to delete old records so that i will still have at least 10 weeks of data before (in the raw data and processed data tables)

Comment: Why not use a rolling table - as you add new values you can also trim off the old stuff? This would simplify items 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: @ethrbunny: efficient rolling table with fast delete and  fast import (5 is very important) with taking into account that every record must have unique id which i have achieved by auto incremented id would be not bad solution , i would apprithiate if you describe your solution through answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a real answer on this question since it depends on your data. But let me give you some things to think about.

1. I assume we're talking about some kind of logs with recent data (so not spanning multiple years). You can partition by range. You could add one field to your table with the year/week number (ie 201201, 201202, etc). If this question is related to your question about importing into multiple tables, you can easily do this is that import script.
2. On the fly as in, repartition your data on the fly (70GB?). I would not recommend it. But you could do it if you had the weeknumber in there. If you later want to change it to 12 days, you could add a column for the date and partition by that.
3. Well it won't be deleted automatically but a cron job can handle that right? Just check how many partitions there are, and if there are 3(?) delete the first one.
4. The partition needs to have a primary index on the field that you partition (if you want to use auto increment). Therefor you can never fully rely on the auto increment id alone. I don't see a way around this.
5. I'm not sure what you mean.

If your data is just some logs in chronological order then you might just use separate tables for each period. Then before you start the new period (at 00:00) check the last id of the last table, create a new table and set the auto increment to that value +1. Then your import will decide when a new period will begin so it can be easily changed. Your import script can use a small table in where it can store the next period.

Comment: +1, thanks, yes the question you have mentioned is related, you provided a very good answer, as regard to 5, i was concerned the case when i import data that may be covered by several partitions (e.g as load data imports block of data without checking constraints),i know that insert automatically knows to which partition to write.

Answer (score 1):

LOAD DATA is really quite fast. I would just have two steps(in no partic order) - LOAD DATA and then 'delete .. where date < 10 weeks'. Autoincrement will go on for as long as the datatype you're using. If you wanted to be super careful you could push it back to zero periodically.

Once the data is in the 'raw' table run your routine to create the 'processed' table. We use a v similar process where I work. We keep a separate table that has 'write' and 'parse' pointers to all of our 'raw' tables. As new data comes in and gets parsed the appropriate row pointers get set. If the 'raw' table gets truncated you can reset the 'write' pointer but leave the 'parse' pointer. (we store the offset in another table when this happens - just to be sure).

Comment: +1, This solution seems relevant, thanks, i wonder how fast are your deletes and if you have indexed your table, additionally, i am interested how you treat memory management, delete does not free memory.

Comment: I trust in MySQL for memory mgmt. We use InnoDB for everything. This strategy manages ~9B records so far.

Comment: -1, sorry then, you shouldn't trust MySQL for everything, and the fact that delete doesn't free memory, and you might get memory overflow is known, the question of many developers is if it is a bug or a feature, there are many ways around it , but not doing nothing is not a solution, SO, or you are not familiar with what exactly is used at your work, or you haven't told me complete and satisfying answer. If you will edit your answer i will up vote it back.

Comment: I have also mentioned that i have MyISAM tables

Answer (score 0):

And if I recommend ,  creating the index column for each of the related columns can also enhanced the performance Delete old data from multiple related tables since we have just compared the index numbers rather than strings.

I wonder if your tables are being sorted or not.

Comment: My tables are partially sorted (they are not sorted by time, only by auto increment id)